# Use the value of method to next method

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I want to code like this

```html
MyClass(variable_1).Method_1(variable_2).Method_2()
```

Where Method_1 give you two values:a data frame and a numpy float; and I want when you call Method_2 graph the values given by Method_1

How can I connect the values of the Method_1 with Method_2 when call it or how it could be possible?
I have the code for dataframe and graph but I can't link them

Comment: The syntax is fine. You just need to ensure that `Method_2` is an attribute of whatever `Method_1` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to return `self` to allow chained calls.
Here is an example:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
        self.var2 = ""
    
    def method1(self,var2):
        self.var2 = var2
        return self
    
    def method2(self):
        print(self.var, self.var2)
```

It works like this

```
>>> MyClass('foo').method1('bar').method2()
foo bar
```

You can adapt this pattern to match your needs. But the data has to be stored inside the class as you need to return `self` to allow chaining the methods. So `self.var2` could be your data frame and `method2` will plot it.

Dependign on your needs, you could also think of returning not `self` but instead an instance of a different class which provides the mehtods you need.

---- Update ----

considering the Code in your answer it could work like this. As I don't have your data I did not test it. There might be still errors in it.

```
class Resumidor():
    def __init__(self,datos,perspectiva='horario',*args):
        self.datos=datos
        self.perspectiva=perspectiva
        self._k = None
        
    def contar_diasxhora(self):    
        k=np.zeros((24,1))
        for i in range(0,24):
            k[i,0]=np.count_nonzero(self.datos.iloc[i,:])
        k2=k[k>0].mean()
        k=pd.DataFrame(data=k,columns=['dias promedio por hora'])
        self._k = (k, k2)
        return self
        
    def gbarrah_horas(self,tipo):
        if not self._k:
            return
        k, k2 = self._k 
        #grafica
        plt.rcdefaults()
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        y_pos = np.arange(24)
        ax.barh(y_pos,k.values[:,0],color='red')
        ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
        ax.set_ylabel('Hora')
        ax.set_xlabel('Deficit [MW]')
        ax.set_title('Maximo deficit por hora')
        plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried but give me this
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-2b0b79544c5d> in <module>
----> 1 Resumidor(deficit_BCA).contar_diasxhora().gbarrah_horas()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'gbarrah_horas'

Comment: Please Share your code in the question. Like this it is not clear what you are doing.

Comment: I write it on the answers

Comment: I edit with out comments in code and like it works

Answer (score 0):

```html
class Resumidor():
    def __init__(self,datos,perspectiva='horario',*args):
        self.datos=datos
        self.perspectiva=perspectiva
        
    def contar_diasxhora(self):    
        k=np.zeros((24,1))
        for i in range(0,24):
            k[i,0]=np.count_nonzero(self.datos.iloc[i,:])
        k2=k[k>0].mean()
        k=pd.DataFrame(data=k,columns=['dias promedio por hora'])
        return k,k2
        
    def gbarrah_horas(self,tipo):
        #que se quiere graficar: contar, promedio, maximo
        if tipo=='contar':
            k,k2=self.contar_diasxhora()
        elif tipo=='promedio':
            k,k2=self.promedio_deficitxhoras()
        elif tipo=='maximo':
            k,k2=self.deficit_maximoxhoras() 
        #grafica
        plt.rcdefaults()
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        y_pos = np.arange(24)
        ax.barh(y_pos,k.values[:,0],color='red')
        ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
        ax.set_ylabel('Hora')
        ax.set_xlabel('Deficit [MW]')
        ax.set_title('Maximo deficit por hora')
        plt.show()
```

I want to call like this:  Resumidor(deficit_BCA).contar_diasxhoras().gbarrah_horas();
Deficit_BCA is a DataFrame, I write "tipo" in gbarrah_horas() to use the function like Resumidor(deficit_BCA).gbarrah_horas("contar") where call the contar function, but I want like Resumidor(deficit_BCA).contar_diasxhoras().gbarrah_horas()

Comment: I want to delete the if part